# Generating Cucumber report running Specflow

Tags: c#, cucumber, jira-xray

I am working with specflow and need to generate a report in the same format as cucumber, to upload the results to XRay jira plugin. I saw many solutions but it seems that all of them need to use specrun which is no longer supported for .NET 6. I didn't see any solution on the Specflow site.

https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/4426703822353-generating-custom-reports-with-Net-6-0-?page=1

Some body knows another way to get cucumber reports from specflow or import the results to xray?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as per their feedback but let's see if anyone can help out.

Comment: Thanks Sérgio for your comment, if generating cucumber reports is no longer possible I will try to import Xunit or Nunit. Do you know if scenario outlines are well imported to Xray when using this type to reports?

Comment: With Nunit or XUnit reports you can import the results back to Xray, including from scenario outline (please check this tutorial: https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32806666). However, you won't have information about the gherkin statetements; just about the overall test result.

Comment: In this respect, just to add here some info from the SpecFlow team and the community discussing this with: https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/4410014094737--NET-6-support-for-the-SpecFlow-Runner

Comment: Yes,  this thread sends you to the link I just added to my post.

Comment: this solution (docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32806666) is generating new tests and adding them to the test execution, I want that the result to be mapped.

Comment: the link that I shared creates "Test" entities, if needed, based on the NUnit XML report. Then it creates a Test Run for each Test. It doesn't allow any special mapping; it's just a way to have visibility of the overall results

Comment: Got it, but I want to map the results of the Speckflow to the cucumber test I added on a testexecution.

Comment: If you want the gherkin level results, or to map to an existing cucumber test in Xray, you'll need to use the cucumber json report.. but then we're back to the initial problem